# Cannot execute multiple MariaDB queries using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have faced a slight problem with executing SQL query in MariaDB. All PHP variables are not empty and I would like to execute two queries at the same time. In MySQL it is working but in MariaDB server I cannot as I get an error I have a query:

```
UPDATE users SET name = $receivedName, email = $receivedEmail WHERE id = $id1; UPDATE posts SET id = $userid WHERE id = $receivedID
```

The error I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE posts SET id = 50 WHERE id = 56 /* /takechange.php */' at line 1
```

I know it is not a shiny idea to execute two queries which are assigned to single variable, but at the moment I can barely change any code. I guess this is not how to join multiple queries in MariaDB. Can you tell me how to edit this query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather obviously: echo $query; -- although I strongly suspect you have a mis-escaped comment at the end of the first query. also, consider whether users and posts relate in some way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use mysqli Multi Query or execute your statements **separately**.

You have multiple statements being passed as you know.

PHP Manual page on [Multi Query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a
>   semicolon.

Comment: It's a bad idea to even have the multi-query feature enabled -- it is another way for a hacker to do nasties with SQL Injection.  Anyway, there is no real need, nor advantage, to run two queries in a single call.

Comment: @RickJames it explains the Syntax Error. There are times when the calls in multitudes are loaded from somewhere, and they don't want to wrap the stuff in a while loop or other use cases, like a block of code as long as your arm

Comment: @RickJames I thought the reason multi query exists was so you could exec multiple commands without hacker injection? Hence in mysql query you can only exec one?

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why i couldn't exploit more an SQLi vulnerability in my own code, so better to leave it as it is and execute two, as the guys said